# Reverse proxy in aws to s3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, gatsby

I am trying to migrate a Scala play website to GatsbyJS and uploading the build to s3.
My website is multilingual, so the generate gatsby routes are like

```
de-DE/lp/press
nl-NL/lp/press
fr-NL/lp/press
```

The current website can be like

```
example.de
example.nl
fr.example.nl
```

Is there some easy way in aws to take a url like `fr.example.nl/lp/press` and serve from s3 with the url `fr-NL/lp/press`

Comment: Not sure about Gatsby but I've had this problem with a React site. Basic S3 websites only offer a single point of entry, usually index.html, then on React you have to use React Router from index.html to supply the branching,

Answer (score 0):

With S3 you cannot but maybe with Cloudfront yes. Create a S3 Bucket with all website and a cloufront (one for each language).

Example: cloudfront of fr.example.nl pointing to the subfolder (/fr-NL) of the S3 Bucket. Gatsby isn't distribute languages in subdomain, therefore you will have to manually create the link between the languages (language switcher, etc).

There's a [plugin](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/packages/gatsby-i18n/) in order to make gatsby multilingual, but that plugin does subfolder for each language instead of subdomains.